# java method accepts array of objects and a double then returns an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, object, double

I am trying to write a method that accepts the array of houses and a price, priceLimit. I want the method to return an array of houses for the houses whose price is less than or equal to priceLimit. I want to make a pass over the data to determine how big to make the return array. The problem is that I can not figure out how to add House objects from houses array to the lowPriceHouses array. The error I am getting is:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at 
prob3.HouseTester.getLowPriced(HouseTester.java:76) at 
prob3.HouseTester.main(HouseTester.java:52)
```

**The code**

```
private static House[] getLowPriced(House[] houses, double priceLimit) 
{

    House[] lowPriceHouses = null;
    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= houses.length; i++)
    {
        double prices = houses[i].getPrice();
        if (prices <= priceLimit)
            lowPriceHouses[index++] = houses[i];
    }

    return lowPriceHouses;  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is because `lowPriceHouses` is `null`, you've not initialised it.  You will also have problems with your loop, Java arrays are `0` indexed.

So, instead of

```
for (int i = 0; i <= houses.length; i++)
```

You should be using...

```
for (int i = 0; i < houses.length; i++)
```

The problem you have is knowing how many elements will match you are case.

Now, you could mess around with [System.arraycopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) or just use some kind of `List` instead.

You could then use `List#toArray` to convert the list back to an array when you're done with it.

See [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) for more details

**Updated with example**

```
private static House[] getLowPriced(House[] houses, double priceLimit) 
{

    List<House> lowPriceHouses = new ArrayList<House>(houses.length);

    for (int i = 0; i <= houses.length; i++)
    {
        double prices = houses[i].getPrice();
        if (prices <= priceLimit)
            lowPriceHouses.add(houses[i]);
    }

    return lowPriceHouses.toArray(new House[lowPriceHouses.size()]);  
}
```

Comment: When you specify the ArrayList why do you define the length ? I mean isn't it possible that `lowPriceHouses` would be less than the original array ? Wouldn't that hold empty elements ?

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov `ArrayList` is a dynamic array, that is, it can contain more or less items and it will grow as you need it to.  But there is a price to be paid for this.  As the list grows beyond it's current "limit", it needs to be resized.  This is done by adding a few "empty" spaces into it's buffer.  But this takes time and memory to do.  Instead, we provide a "guess" of the number of values we might have.  This makes it faster.  Since we know we will never have more than `houses.length` items, it's safe to use this value as or initialiser.

Comment: I see, so this won't allocate the array it would just set a limit ?

Comment: Thanks. At first I was getting null at the end of my list but making it into an array list then converting it back really helped.

Comment: It sets a "initialCapacity", you can freely run over this limit and the `ArrayList` will grow automatically

Comment: Happy to have helped :D

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yeah I think I'm confusing capacity with size. Thanks for explaining +1.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the array before you write to it.

```
House[] lowPriceHouses = null;
```

should be something like

```
House[] lowPriceHouses = new House[houses.length];
```

you actually want a smaller array since, you might not need all houses.. 
It would be easier to make this a `ArrayList` and then convert it `toArray` before returning.

---

```
for (int i = 0; i <= houses.length; i++)
```

You want to do only `<`

This is because when you have an array of size 10, the elements are indexed from 0 - 9. Thus accessing the element `arr[10]` will lead to issues.

Comment: I am still getting an error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at prob3.HouseTester.getLowPriced(HouseTester.java:76) at prob3.HouseTester.main(HouseTester.java:52)

Comment: @KelliDavis there are 2 problems, I have updated it with both, take a look.

Comment: Just as an aside, this sort of task seems to be better suited to a Set than a List.  It may be that a list of Houses has some kind of inherent order such that an index is naturally associated with a House ... but, I'm thinking it's not what I'd expect here.  You're really just dealing with a collection of Houses.  If this were me, I'd make my life simpler by simply returning a Collection of Houses (Set, List, whatever).

Comment: @scottb you might want to either link to OP or better yet comment on the question, else he may not see this

Answer (score 0):

You lowPriceHouses  is Null so you are getting NullPointerException. Please replace with below code

```
private static House[] getLowPriced(House[] houses, double priceLimit)  {
    List<House> lowPriceHouses  = new ArrayList<House>()
    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= houses.length; i++)
    {
         double prices = houses[i].getPrice();
         if (prices <= priceLimit)
           lowPriceHouses.add(houses[i]);
    }

    return lowPriceHouses.toArray(new House[lowPriceHouses.size()]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you are using Java 8, you could do this:

```
public static House[] getLowPriced(final House[] houses, final double limit){
    final List<House> list = Arrays.asList(houses).stream().filter(h -> h.getPrice() <= limit).sorted(Comparator.comparing(House::getPrice)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return list.toArray(new House[list.size()]);
}
```

Comment: Boy ... that sure is ugly to look at.